# Linux: get list of files and dirs along with mime info

Tags: linux, file, search, find, ls

What command can I use to find the following info when a dir is provided as argument ?

1. Size of files in (human readable format)
2. Date an time stamp of files (human readable format)
3. File-name without path
4. Mime of file (Text File,Image File etc)
5. Possible use of maxdepth option in find

I tired this one

```
find /home/dojo50  -name "*" -exec file {} \;
```

But it lacks file size and datetime info.
Is it possible to combine `File` with `ls` in `find` .

something like but doesnot work

```
find /home -name "*" -maxdepth 1  -exec ls -lh {} \; -exec file {} \;
```

Comment: This feels like homework, but you can `man find` and look at the `-printf` option for 1,2,3. Your example should already work for 4. Not sure what you mean by 5.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the `-name "*"` bit? Seems a bit pointless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `mime-type` use `file` command in `-exec` option and for other item use `-printf` options. like:

```
find * -printf "%kK %AD %AT %p " -exec file -b {} \;
```

see `man find` for more information.

Comment: The `*` here is a mistake. It's going to get processed by the shell, which isn't a huge issue since `find` can take a list, but it's going to depend on shell options as to whether it will actually get all files/dirs in the working directory.

Comment: What @BrowSlow says. It might e.g. skip dotfiles and unnecessarily slow down the query if you have lots of files in a directory that need to be expanded first.